# OpenLDAP's cn=config is not getting fully replicated

Tags: ldap, openldap, replication

I've got OpenLDAP 2.4.39 master and a read-only replica, using the `cn=config` aka *"OLC"* configuration (as oppose to the older `slapd.conf` method).

Replication works for data (user accounts, etc) but not for the config - when I change the configuration on master using `ldapmodify`, e.g. in `dn: cn=config` the replica notices the change and updates `contextCSN: ...` timestamp in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif` but doesn't accept the changed data. Tested for example with changing `olcGentleHUP: ...` property.

On the master the record `olcGentleHUP: ...` in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif` is updated together with the `contextCSN: ...` timestamp, on the replica only the `contextCSN: ...` timestamp is updated to the very same value as on the master.

Any idea what's going on here? How can I debug it?

**Update (2/07/2015)**

Turns out we had `searchbase="cn=schema,cn=config"` in the `olcSyncrepl` setting on the slave. Changed that to `searchbase="cn=config"` and now the whole config is synchronised.

Answer (score 4):

Have you set up replication for the OLC in `olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config` in addition to for the data in `oldDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config`?  Basically, `cn=config` replicating would need a special bootstrap procedure [explained in the manual](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html#N-Way%20Multi-Master).

My working configuration (in mirror mode) looks like this:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage by * break
olcRootDN: cn=config
olcRootPW:: hogehogehogehoge==
olcSyncrepl: {0}rid=001 provider=ldap://server1/ starttls=critical tls_reqcert=demand bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=config" credentials=secret searchbase="cn=config" type=refreshAndPersist retry="5 5 300 5" timeout=1
olcSyncrepl: {1}rid=002 provider=ldap://server2/ starttls=critical tls_reqcert=demand bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=config" credentials=secret searchbase="cn=config" type=refreshAndPersist retry="5 5 300 5" timeout=1
olcMirrorMode: TRUE

dn: olcOverlay={0}syncprov,olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: {0}syncprov

dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=your,dc=domain
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by .... read by .... write by dn="cn=config" read
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by .... write by * read
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcRootDN: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
olcSyncrepl: {0}rid=011 provider=ldap://server1/ starttls=critical tls_reqcert=demand bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=config" credentials=secret searchbase="dc=your,dc=domain" type=refreshAndPersist retry="60 +" timeout=1
olcSyncrepl: {1}rid=012 provider=ldap://server2/ starttls=critical tls_reqcert=demand bindmethod=simple binddn="cn=config" credentials=secret searchbase="dc=your,dc=domain" type=refreshAndPersist retry="60 +" timeout=1
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
olcDb....: ... (other hdb configuration)

dn: olcOverlay={0}syncprov,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcSyncProvConfig
olcOverlay: {0}syncprov
```

The point is to use `olcRootDN` and `olcRootPW` to set up `cn=config` credential for the replicators (`syncprov`) to bind on the peer server.  You also need to set up appropriate `olcAccess` so that they can fetch everything from the peer.  No need to grant write permission to them, because they already know how to update their own local database.